# Существует ли способ включения поддержки RAW сокетов в Windows 8\10?

Tags: c#, .net

Существует ли способ включения поддержки RAW (сырых) сокетов в Windows 8\10?

Comment: А `SocketType = Raw` не подходит?

Comment: @nick_n_a, нет. Выдает исключение, даже при запуске с правами Администратора. На серверных осях отлично работает. Нашел инфу: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx тут, раздел "Limitations on Raw Sockets". Хотелось бы понять, как обойти это неадекватное ограничение MS на клиентские оси, кроме использования WinPcap. В XP, помнится, патчили системные файлы.

Comment: @nick_n_a, имею ввиду TCP.